# tkinter buttons dont work when i start python script

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

When I launch my Tkinter GUI and start python3 script with button, GUI is no more responding to other clicks. So basically I can't stop running the script. Is there a problem that i can't run two python scripts at the same time or the code has mistakes.

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script")
window.geometry('550x200')
def run():
    os.system('python3 03_face_recognition.py')
def kill():
    os.system('pkill -f 03_face_recognition.py')

btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", bg="black", fg="white",command=run)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0)
btn = Button(window, text="kill Me", bg="black", fg="white",command=kill)
btn.grid(column=100, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

[Kill button becomes gray and not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFU60.png)

Comment: `os.system()` does not return until the launched process exits - so once you press the run button, your GUI is locked up.  You need to use something like `subprocess.Popen()` that launches a process but doesn't wait for it to complete; you can kill the process through methods of the returned object.

Answer (score 1):

In `tkinter` (and most if not all GUI toolkits), callback functions like your `run` and `kill` are called *inside the mainloop*. For the program to stay responsive, the `mainloop` needs to keep processing events.

That means you should never use code that blocks or takes a long time inside a callback. So no `while True` loops and no `os.system`, `subprocess.run`.
Long running tasks should be run in either separate threads or separate processes.

One thing you can do in this case is use `subprocess.Popen`. This creates a new process, but doesn't wait for it to finish.

```
import subprocess as sp

def run():
    sp.Popen(
        ['python3', '03_face_recognition.py'],
        stdout=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.DEVNULL
    )


def kill():
    sp.Popen(
        ['pkill', '-f', '03_face_recognition.py'],
        stdout=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.DEVNULL
    )
```

Another option would be to *import* the code from `03_face_recognition.py` (let's assume it has a function called `recognize`) and start in in a separate process using `multiprocessing.Process`. Note that in this case your code (except for the function definitions) should be within a `main` block:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import tkinter as tk
from 03_face_recognition import recognize


def run():
    global proc
    proc = mp.Process(target=recognize)
    proc.start()


def kill():
    proc.terminate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Running Python Script")
    window.geometry('550x200')
    btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", bg="black", fg="white",command=run)
    btn.grid(column=0, row=0)
    btn = Button(window, text="kill Me", bg="black", fg="white",command=kill)
    btn.grid(column=100, row=0)
    proc = None
    window.mainloop()
```